# Multi Terms search NEST C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to do a search matching multiple values ( an array of values ) like this :

```
var result1 = _client.Search<type1>(s => s
            .Fields(f => f.trip_id)
            .Query(q => q
                .Terms(t => t.arg1, value1)).Take(_allData))
                .Documents.Select(d => d.arg2).ToArray();

var result2 = _client.Search<type2>(s => s
                      .Query(q => q
                          .Terms(t => t.arg3, result1))
                          .Take(_allData)
                          ).Documents.Select(s => s.ar3).ToList();
```

How can I do ? I was thinking about facets but I don't see how I can do it.
The only way for now that works is with a `foreach` iterator which is not really effective...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can express multiple queries like so:

```
.Query(q=>q.Terms(t=>t.arg3, result1) && q.Terms(t=>t.arg1, value1))
```

Be sure to read the [documentation on writing queries](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/writing-queries.html) to discover all the good stuff NEST has to offer.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but finally I used the `Filter DSL` and not the `Query DSL` which allowed me to pass :
`.And(
        af=>af.Term(...), 
        af=>af.Term(...)
    )`

Comment: Could you update the URL above?  It is currently not available.

Comment: t.arg1 should be t=>t.arg1

Comment: @Orelus You should write your comment as an answer because it is the correct answer and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Orelus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2265812/orelus),
I'd like to use your solution with

```
.And( af=>af.Term(...), af=>af.Term(...) )
```

I don't understand where this fits, here's an example of my non-working filter

```
var results = client.Search<music>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Filtered(f => f.
            Filter(b => b.Bool(m => m.Must(
                t => t
                    .Term(p => p.artist, artist)
                     && t.Term(p2 => p2.year, year)
                )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    );
```