# how to get request with multiple conditions in C# with elastic search

Tags: c#, select, elasticsearch, request

I have a base in elasticsearch with data, and correct request with results.

```
var searchResults = _client.Search<Apartment>(s => s
    .Size(pageSize)
    .Query(d => d.Term(t => t.Field(apartment => apartment.IsDeleted).Value(false))
                        && (d.Terms(t => t.Field(car => car.Host).Terms(hosts))))
    .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.CollectedDate))
    .Scroll(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
    .Index(Index));
```

But i can't add new filter to request. Can you help me? I read this [Multi Terms search NEST C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213874/multi-terms-search-nest-c-sharp) and tried next requests:

```
var searchResults2 = _client.Search<Apartment>(s => s
.Size(pageSize)
.Query(d => d.Term(t => t.Field(apartment => apartment.IsDeleted).Value(false))
                    && (d.Terms(t => t.Field(car => car.Host).Terms(hosts)))
                    && (d.Terms(t => t.Field(car => car.Transaction).Terms(dealTypeStr))))
.Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.CollectedDate))
.Scroll(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
.Index(Index));

var total2 = searchResults2.Total;

var searchResults3 = _client.Search<Apartment>(s => s
.Size(pageSize)
.Query(q => q
    .Bool(b => b
        .Must(d => d.Term(t => t.Field(apartment => apartment.IsDeleted).Value(false))
                    && (d.Terms(t => t.Field(car => car.Host).Terms(hosts)))
                    && (d.Terms(t => t.Field(car => car.Transaction).Terms(dealTypeStr))))))

.Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.CollectedDate))
.Scroll(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
.Index(Index));
var total3 = searchResults3.Total;


var searchResults4 = _client.Search<Apartment>(s => s
.Size(pageSize)
.Query(q => q
    .Bool(b => b
        .Must(d => d.Term(t => t.Field(apartment => apartment.IsDeleted).Value(false))
                    && (d.Terms(t => t.Field(car => car.Host).Terms(hosts)))
                    && (d.Term(f => f.Transaction, dealTypeStr)))))
.Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.CollectedDate))
.Scroll(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
.Index(Index));
var total4 = searchResults4.Total;
```

And have empty results. I didn't correct? 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dealTypeStr is single string. 
In this case your request should look like this.

```
var searchResults = _client.Search<Apartment>(s => s
    .Size(pageSize)
    .Query(d => d.Term(t => t.Field(apartment => apartment.IsDeleted).Value(false))
            && d.Term(t => t.Field(apartment => apartment.Transaction).Value(dealTypeStr))
                        && (d.Terms(t => t.Field(car => car.Host).Terms(hosts))))
    .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.CollectedDate))
    .Scroll(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
    .Index(Index));
```

Comment: thank you for correct syntaxis! But it does not work for me because another problem - not utf-8 value param for filter