# Searching multiple fields using term query in OpenSearch / ElasticSearch .NET clients

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, client, dsl, opensearch

I'm having problem to reproduce search result in OpenSearch / ElasticSearch from DSL query to .NET C# code base.

Index was populated from .NET Core application based on this model:

```
public class Car
    {
        public string Producer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Vin { get; set; }
        public ColorEnum Color { get; set; }
        public TransmissionType Transmission { get; set; }
        public CategoryType Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Index mapping for model above looks like this:

```
"mappings": {
  "_doc": {
    "properties": {
      "transmission": {
       "type": "long"
      },
      "color": {
       "type": "long"
      },
      "producer": {
       "type": "text",
       "fields": {
       "keyword": {
        "ignore_above": 256,
        "type": "keyword"
        }
       }
      },
     "model": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
       "keyword": {
        "ignore_above": 256,
        "type": "keyword"
       }
      }
     },
     "vin": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
       "keyword": {
        "ignore_above": 256,
        "type": "keyword"
        }
       }
      },
      "category": {
       "type": "long"
       }
      }
     }
```

Below is working as expected DSL query

```
{
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    { "term": { "color": 0 }},
                    { "term": { "transmission": 0 }},
                    { "term": { "producer": "volvo" } }
                    ]}}
}
```

The C# query that uses OpenSearch or ElasticSearch .NET Client and should produce that same outcome as DSL query is not respecting all required terms.

```
            var documents = await _openSearchClient.SearchAsync<Car>(s => s
                .Index(_indexName)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Must(m => m.Term("category", 0))
                        .Must(m => m.Term("transmission", 0))
                        .Must(m => m.Term("producer", producer)))));

             return documents?.Documents;
```

The outcome of C# API call contain also documents that have category values set to 1 and transmission set to 1. It looks like only last term with producer name is respected.

Do i made mistake in c# query or there is something how to queries are executed ?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You could try looking into @Martijn Laarman answer in this post, which might be relevant for you  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213874/multi-terms-search-nest-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution based on input from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213874/multi-terms-search-nest-c-sharp)

```
  var documents = await _openSearchClient.SearchAsync<Car>(s => s
            .Index(_indexName)
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(bq => bq
                    .Must(mq => mq
                      .Term("transmission", 0) 
                                && mq.Term("color",0) 
                                && mq.Term("producer",producer)))));
```